# Error when importing the returned value of a function in a different module using Python

Tags: python

I have a file (`calculations`) with a defined function called `number`, whose return value is `i` when executed. Now, I have defined a function in a different file and want to print the value `i`. However, when I try to "import" `i`, I get an error message saying that `i` cannot be imported.

This is my code (where `i` is supposed to be imported from the function `number` that is defined in `calculations`)

```
import calculations

def myfunction():
    calculations.number()
    print(calculations.i)
```

Apparently, executing `myfunction()` without the `print(calculations.i)` statement works successfully. But when I try to import `i` following the same method, it doesn't. I have also tried using `from calculations import i`, though it doesn't work either. It probably has to do with the fact that the last time it was "mentioned" in the `number()`function was as `return i` (though this might not be the problem), or with the fact that it's not part of the `calculations` file itself, but it's within the definition of one of functions stored in that file...

In any case, what's happening and how can I import this value?

Edit: This is the code in the file `calculations`:

```
def number():
    a = 2
    i = 0
    while a < 100
        a = a + 2
        i = i+1
    return i
```

Comment: Could we see how `i` is defined in the `calculations` file?

Comment: You can import functions from modules, but not variables within those functions. If you want to import a variable it has to be defined globally in `calculations`.

Comment: Can you please add whole code, that will be more clear to understand where is the actual problem

Comment: @berkelem what if I transferred `def myfunction()` to the `calculations` file? Would I be able then to refer to the `i` variable from the function `number` within the function `myfunction` now that both functions are part of the same file?

Comment: No because `i` is only defined (presumably) within the function `number`, i.e. it is defined locally not globally. For any other function to access it it would need to be defined globally. The best way for you to proceed is to call `number()` and assign the output to a variable. `myvar = calculations.number()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not import variables which is local to the function, below are some approach with which you can use that variable

**Solution 1:**

This is the code in the file calculations:

```
def number():
    a = 2
    i = 0
    while a < 100
        a = a + 2
        i = i+1
    return i
```

You can call number inside myfunction and assign it to some variable let's say i

```
import calculations

def myfunction():
    i = calculations.number()
    print(i)
```

**Solution 2:**

**Or you can do this:**

This is the code in the file calculations:

```
i = number()
def number():
    a = 2
    j = 0
    while a < 100
        a = a + 2
        j = j+1
    return j
```

Your myfunction

```
import calculations
def myfunction():
    print(calculations.i)
```

**Solution 3:**

**Or you can do this:**

This is the code in the file calculations:

```
global i = 0
def number():
    a = 2
    while a < 100
        a = a + 2
        i = i+1
    return i
```

Your myfunction

```
import calculations
def myfunction():
    print(calculations.i)
```

Comment: Solution 2 is wrong because you're using `i` twice and expecting it to do different things. If you are assigning the output of `number()` to `i` then you can't also use `i` as a variable within `number()`.

Comment: @berkelem It should work, I checked it on python2.7 and 3.5 and on both solution 2 is working, there is no issue with using `i` twice

Comment: That's surprising. In any case, it's bad practice to reuse variables like that. It can lead to all sorts of problems that are difficult to debug.

Comment: @berkelem that's another point that if you use the same variable twice for two different purposes that may lead to some confusion but in some small part of the code it is completely fine, and also as one of them is local to function then it will be completely fine to use another one outside the function